# how can i use Gridview.count inside Column flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use `Gridview` inside column which is also scrollable because there is 100+ rows

for scrollable I am using `CustomScrollView` and `SliverFillRemaining` here is full code

```
Expanded(
              child: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
                SliverFillRemaining(
                  hasScrollBody: false,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                        child: GridView.count(  <--- here i want to use Gridview
                          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                          primary: false,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 5,
                          children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                            return Expanded(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Item $index',
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                        ),
                      )),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right: 4, left: 8, top: 12),
                              child: OutlinedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _save();
                                },
                                child: Text('ok (F9)'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
```

when I use `Text` widget like this

```
Column(
      children: [
        Container(
           child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
               child: Text('there should be gridview')
           )
        ),
      ],
),
```

its working fine

how can I use Gridview inside Column

Comment: why the parent widget is `Expanded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main conflicts here are between `CustomScrollView` and `GridView`. Both are scrollable, and on your widget make `hasScrollBody:true`, then comes the overflow issue, you can provide height on `Column>> Cotainer` or wrap with `Expanded`.

**Result**

[image]

**Widget**

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String a = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
          // Expanded(
          //   child:
          CustomScrollView(slivers: [
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: true,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  // height: 200, /// here or [Expanded]
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                    child: GridView.count(
                      //<--- here i want to use Gridview
                      crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                      primary: false,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      crossAxisCount: 5,
                      children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                        return
                            // Flexible( /// we dont need this, 
                            //   child:
                            Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Item $index',
                          ),
                          // ),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4, left: 8, top: 12),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // _save();
                        },
                        child: Text('ok (F9)'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ]),
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks it's working. but when I adding row to parent again showing me error

Comment: Ahh its fixed thanks

Comment: Glad to help you out.